# How to do a python range with offset

Tags: python

Is there a way to do the following offset using the range function?

```
range(1,100, offset=10)
10,11,12,13...
```

In other words, what is the best way to do an offset with a range?

Comment: Why can't you just do `range(10, 110)`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What would that accomplish over `range(10, 110)`, exactly?

Comment: Note that your offset combined with your current startpoint of `1` suggests you want the series to start at *eleven*, not ten.

Comment: Is there any thing extra you want to achieve with this other than `range(10,110)` as Martijn has pointed out?! or You want some kind of your own range function which i think is not needed too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you include two parameters, the first parameter of [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is the first element of the range:

```
offset = 10
for i in range(offset, 100 + offset):
    print(i)
```

If you don't want the end point to move by the offset too, simply remove the `+ offset` from the second argument.

Comment: `range(0 + offset, 100 + offset)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to apply the offset to the results of range at runtime:

```
offset = 10
for i in map(lambda x: x + offset, range(100)):
    print(i)
```

will print

```
10
11
...
108
109
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `numpy`, there is a very simple and elegant solution:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(100)

offset = 10
stride = 1
idx = np.r_[1:2, 3:4, 6:8]*stride+offset

print(a[idx])
## [11 13 16 17]
a[idx] = 0
print(a[:20])
## [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  0 12  0 14 15  0  0 18 19]
```